# How do I create a new GoClipse project so that it follows the normal Go project structure?

Tags: go, goclipse

My Environment:

- OS X 10.10.5
- Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)
- GoClipse 0.13.0
- go version go1.5.2 darwin/amd64

My GoClipse Settings:

- Eclipse workspace: /Users/ray/go_workspace
- Go Installation

  - GOROOT: /usr/local/go
  - gofmt: /usr/local/go/bin/gofmt
  - godoc: /usr/local/go/bin/godoc
  - GOOS:
  - GOARCH:
  - GOPATH: [x] Same as GOPATH env variable (which is /Users/ray/go)
- Tools

  - Go oracle path: /Users/ray/go/bin/oracle
  - [x] Start gocode server automatically
  - [x] Enable gocode log console
  - gocode path: /Users/ray/go/bin/gocode

When I create a new Go project using default settings, the project folder is put under the eclipse workspace: /Users/ray/go_workspace/project with the bin, pkg, and src folders as subfolders.

What I want to do is create a new Go project and have it use:

- /Users/ray/go/src/github/user/project for the source directory
- /Users/ray/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github/user/project for the package directory
- /Users/ray/go/bin for the binary directory
- /Users/ray/go_workspace/user/project for any Eclipse/GoClipse settings

How do I configure Eclipse/GoClipse/Project settings to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the above is not possible. The closest you can get is creating your Eclipse project in the location `/Users/ray/go/src/github/user/project` (note that beforehand you will need to set the Eclipse preferences GOPATH to `/Users/ray/go`). This way you will have:

- `/Users/ray/go/src/github/user/project` for the source directory
- `/Users/ray/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github/user/project` for the package directory
- `/Users/ray/go/bin` for the binary directory

but Eclipse settings/files will be in `/Users/ray/go/src/github/user/project`. (ATM, the only Eclipse files are `.project` and `.settings/`. You can add these to Git ignore if you are concerned about them appearing in version control)